# Dynamically creating radio buttons and selected appropriate button Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a questionnaire form that loops over questions and the answers in the questions and then creates radio buttons with the answers.  The answer object will have a property of answered which will either be true or false depending on whether or not that answer had been previously selected for the item.  If answer.answered = true, that radio button should be checked(only one will have been answered).  The problem is is that I can not get the appropriate radio button to be checked based on answer.answered.  I have tried ng-value="answer.answered", setting the model on init.  Abbreviated code below.

```
 <md-card data-ng-repeat="question in gradeCtrl.questions | limitTo: 1  track by $index" class="questions main-questions" 
data-ng-if="!gradeCtrl.subQuestions && gradeCtrl.needsRepairs === false">
<ul data-ng-repeat="answer in question.answers track by $index" class="questionnaire" layout-wrap layout="column" layout-align="center center">
<li>
<input type="radio" name="{{question.id}}" data-ng-attr-id="answer.id" data-ng-value="gradeCtrl.isAnswered(answer);"
 data-ng-init="gradeCtrl.radioButton[answer.id]=gradeCtrl.isAnswered(answer);"
 data-ng-model="gradeCtrl.radioButton[answer.id]">
</li>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Just an FYI your `data-ng-repeat` should be on the `li` element not the `ul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by setting the model = answer.answered as well as using ng-checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="{{question.id}}"  data-ng-checked="gradeCtrl.isAnswered(answer);"
                       data-ng-attr-id="answer.id"
                       data-ng-init="gradeCtrl.radioButton[answer.id] = gradeCtrl.isAnswered(answer);"
                       data-ng-click="gradeCtrl.saveAnswer(answer, question.question)"
                       data-ng-model="answer.answered">
```